# Mongodb knowing if find works

Tags: mongodb

I want to check if a document exists in my table users. How can I check the return value of find to make it be automatic

```
echo "db.users.find({username : \"test\"})" | mongo users
if [ "$!" = "0" ]
then
    echo "OK"
fi
```

This doesn't work because find doesn't return 0 on success, how to know if it worked ?

Comment: `"db.users.find({username : \"test\"}).limit(1).count()"` or even `"db.users.find({username : \"test\"}).limit(1).count() > 0"` for a direct boolean return. I know I've seen the duplicate question before.

Comment: better yet `mongo --eval "db.users.find({username : \"test\"}).limit(1).count()" users`

Comment: Both works but how can I check the number returned ?

Comment: Well you can remove the `.limit()` but I thought you were asking if it "exists". For which the `.limit()` is a performance gain if you do not need the total "count".